# How to get Kubernetes HTTP Request response in yaml instead of json

Tags: kubernetes, httprequest

I i'm making Kubernetes HTTP Request
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}

This gives response in json but i want response in json.

Does Kubernetes give response in yaml? if yes, let me know how to do it?

Comment: are you using Kubectl or curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running curl requests you can tell api-server to send you yaml formated output by setting `Accept: application/yaml` header. Take a look at example below:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/yaml" "/apis/[...]"
```

Or you can also use some external tool to convert from json to yaml, e.g. `yq`:

```
curl "/apis/[...]" | yq -y .
```

where `-y` stands for yaml output.